# MVC and Mysql conceptual dilemma - Want to retrieve mysql data from the VIEW for a list of items that is returned from the CONTROLLER

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, codeigniter

This may be chalked up to exhaustion, but I am new to MVC programming and while I have some grasp on it, I am really struggling with a concept. I am working in php/codeigniter on a system that allows a user to post entries and other users are able to vote on them. I have stored the entries in a mysql table *entries* and the votes in another table *votes*.

The field that links them together would be *entries->id* and *votes->entryId*.

So, in my **controller**, I have a function that calls the model and gets the recent entries:

```
$data['recentEntries'] = $this->Entries->getRecentEntries($id);
```

where *$id* is the id number of the user's entries you want to get.

I want to be able to display each entry alongside the corresponding votes for each entry, and normally without MVC I would simply find all the entries for a user, then in a foreach loop, find and display all the votes for each particular *entryId*.

However, with MVC, the entries are loaded into the variable $data['recentEntries'] and I wouldn't or shouldn't use the foreach loop to query mysql in the **view**.

I feel like I am missing a critical mysql or MVC concept here that should take care of this quite simply, so any direction or guiding would be incredibly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

-- Update --

So I've updated the **controller** so:

```
$data['recentEntries'] = $this->Entries->getRecentEntries($id);

$data['votes'] = array();

foreach ($data['recentEntries'] as $entry) {
    array_push($data['votes'], $this->Votes->getVotes($entry->id));
}
```

So that *$data['votes']* now contains the votes for all the entries for a particular user. **Is this the right way to go about it?** If so, then once in the **view's** foreach loop, how do I find and display the appropriate values from this *$data['votes']* array?

**View:**

```
if (count($recentEntries)>0) {
    foreach ($recentEntries as $row)
    {
        echo $row->content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably to maintain it as a map rather than a simple array so that you maintain the association between an entry and it's votes.  And, yes, I think it's best to populate the entire model in the controller rather than querying the DB from the view.

```
foreach ($data['recentEntries'] as $entry) {
     $data['votes'][$entry->id] = $this->Votes->getVotes($entry->id);
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, I updated my view as follows:

`foreach ($recentEntries as $row) {
 if (count($votes[$row->id]) > 0) {
  ...
 }
}`

Thank you for the help!